# Property date to String for parsing

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I'm trying to insert creation date into table view in specific format.

Now it's like `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:ss` and I want it like `DD/MM/YYYY`.

```
YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("registerRenderer", {
   propertyName: "test:date", 
   renderer: function functionPrice(record, label){
      var jsNode = record.jsNode,
      properties = jsNode.properties;
      var rawDate = properties['test:date'];

      var date= rawDate().toString().substring(0, 11);

      return '<div id="attachments">' + date + '</div>';
   } 
});
```

In this case, column contains `[Object obj`.
I also tried convert it to `toISOString` but it returns `Invalid Date`.

Column is set like `d:date` but output is `d:datetime` and I don't know why.

Thank you.

Comment: `date = date.split(' ')[0]` - there is no date in your code

Comment: @mplungjan I have tried to create date with `value` like `var d = new Date(value);` but it return `Invalid Date`. However, `value`should be date from creating document. Property `value` is date of creation of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change dates the dates displayed in the date picker control, but this file may not exist in your environment.  See if the following file exists:

```
<alfresco home>\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form\form.get_en.properties
```

If it doesn’t exist, copy it from here (create the form folder if necessary):

```
<alfresco home>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form\form.get_en.properties
```

Open the form.get_en.properties file for editing.  Search for “form-control.date-picker” to find the proper properties to change (we found four values on a recent installation).

Restart Alfresco to make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 1):

If your date format is fixed, this is a [safe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) way to create a `Date` instance:

```
var value = "31/12/2017 00:00:00";
var dd = value.substring(0,2);
var mm = value.substring(3,5);
var yyyy = value.substring(6,10);
var d = new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd); // Sun Dec 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)
```

Comment: My problem is that I cannot create datum from `value`, because it returns `Invalid date`. And If I try to substing `value`, it returns `function undefined`.

Comment: That's the point - it returns also `Invalid date` but if I let it like it is, without formating, whole function returns `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:ss`.

Comment: I don't know what to show you.
I'll try to explain better:

new Date
`console.log(new Date(finalValue); // Output - Invalid Date`

new Date with toString
`console.log(new Date(finalValue.toString())); // Output - Invalid Date`

substring
`console.long(new Date(finalValue.substring(0, 10)); // - Error: undefined function.`

Comment: Sorry', this was my fault - both of them are same, I just tried create new var 'value' like 'new Date()' from 'finalValue'. Both of them are 'Object' via '.valueOf()'. In this case value and finalValue are date but not parsed. So it could be 'rawDate'. If I print 'rawDate', it returns '[Object object]', if I try to create date with this variable, it returns 'Invalid Date'.

Comment: I wrote that in `value` (now rawDate for consistent variables), after `rawDate
= properties["test:date"]` is Object with creation date of a document. But if I cast it to String, output into console is `Invalid Date` and if I want to create date with `new Date(rawDate)` it returns also `Invalid Date`.

Comment: problem was that I didn't look at it like another Dictionary. So solution is `var key = object['key'];`
`var date = new Date(key);` and then I can parse it like you suggest me or straight with date.getDate()/date.getMonth(), etc.
Thank you for your help.